# Show dapp favicon in trustwallet

Tags: metamask, dapps, trustwallet

I have a very small and silly problem. I have developed a dapp. But trustwallet does not show the favicon of the dapp, in its history or in the url as it shows for other dapps like Pancakeswap. While Metamask shows the favicon.

This is the html to show the icon:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Is there anything else I need to do to show that favicon in TrustWallet?
I need to do this, my client is stubborn.

Comment: I actually have the exact same problem, but for Coinbase Wallet, and MetaMask is also very flaky displaying the favicon. Have you made any progress on this? Thanks.

Comment: No, and it's strange no one answered it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to learn a bit about this, and while this is *not* a complete answer, I will post what I found below for everyone's benefit.

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/issues/1261#issue-546090110), MetaMask uses a *third-party service* called https://faviconkit.com/ in order to populate its favicons. I suspect that Coinbase Wallet may also use it, and maybe also TrustWallet. this service has essentially 0 documentation.

By running a local server, tunneling to it using ngrok, and hitting the external tunnel endpoint with faviconkit.com, I was able to learn which items faviconkit requests in order to populate its favicons. in summary, I found it was enough to do two things:

1. use the webpack plugin [`FaviconsWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin) when you build your project with webpack. use the default configuration. This will result in an `assets/` subdirectory in your output directory, containing a bunch of images (about 40 total or so).
2. in your main output directory, run `cp assets/* .`. That is, duplicate everything in the `assets/` folder to the main (top-level) output directory. *do not* move them; you must duplicate them.

if you do these two things, it seems that you will satisfy faviconkit. BUT there is a further problem—faviconkit is extremely slow to re-cache / refresh, and it is likely that your dapp will have stale favicons for a long time. it has been about a week, and my favicons have NOT refreshed. i do not know of a way to force a refresh of my dapp with faviconkit. hopefully this helps.